# Android Estimate Battery Capacity

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, battery, charging

I have a phone with 3.7v, 1500 mAH genuine battery.

This being said, the maximum power that this battery can hold can be calculated easily:

3.7 v *1500 mAH = 5550 mV.

I'm trying to see what battery actually tells the Android when it's charged by %100 by using Nema's very known battery calibration app and it, unfortunately, says only about 4800 when charged %100 (I'll provide a definitive screenshot soon)

So,

Here is my question: 
Is it possible, that the battery never charges to it's maximum and leaving about %10-%20 uncharged at each charge? And 
If so, is there any way to tell the system to charge the battery until it reaches 5550 mV?

I'd also want to know if people can observe their battery-stated power limit when their Android device charged %100.

I'm talking about this battery http://www.batteryforum.org/t1356-alcatel-ot-995-battery-tli5baa on Alcatel OT-995.

Comment: V * mAH does not equal mV, mV is millivolt, which is a thousandth of a volt. 1500 mAH is milliamp-hours, which means if you were pulling 1500 milliamps, the battery would last for an hour (at full capacity).

Answer (score 2):

I highly doubt you can tell nor force the system to charge to its maximum as that is the SoC that is handling the battery current, in which the kernel is periodically polling to measure the battery charge.

(*You could in theory mess with the values of the threshold within the kernel's specific battery module, but that could have unintended consequences, possibly damage to the battery long term!*)

Observing battery state power limit is subjective and debatable as to each and their own, depends on what they are using on their handset - you're not going to get a concrete answer out of that. :)